# What's the difference between `when:manual` and `only:web` in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

From the documentation:

manual: https://docs.gitlab.com/14.1/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#whenmanual

> A manual job is a type of job that is not executed automatically and
> must be explicitly started by a user. You might want to use manual
> jobs for things like deploying to production.

web: https://docs.gitlab.com/14.1/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs

> For pipelines created by using Run pipeline button in the GitLab UI,
> from the project’s CI/CD > Pipelines section.

they seem to do the same. Just duplicated ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `when: manual`, your pipeline would have a job which you'd need to press a button to trigger.

[image]

---

When using `only: web`, this would enable you to use the `Run Pipeline` button from the GitLab UI CI/CD page, to create a new pipeline.

[image]

Comment: the equivalent condition in rules for `only: web` is `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"`

Comment: If using `when: manual` and `only: web` together on the same job could the same result be achieved by using `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` ?

Answer (score 0):

### when:manual

If you use `when:manual` the job is added to the pipeline, but it is marked as skipped, see [Create a job that must be run manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually):

> **Create a job that must be run manually**
>
> You can require that a job doesn’t run unless a user starts it. This is called a manual job. You might want to use a manual job for something like deploying to production.
>
> To specify a job as manual, add `when: manual` to the job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
>
> By default, manual jobs display as skipped when the pipeline starts.

Example:

A pipeline definition with a build and two deploy jobs. The build job is executed automatically, but the two deploy jobs must started by a user manually.

[image: manual job]

### only: web

If you use `only: web` the job is only added to the pipeline if the pipline is created manually, see [`only:refs` / `except:refs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs):

> **`only:refs` / `except:refs`**
>
> Use the `only:refs` and `except:refs` keywords to control when to add jobs to a pipeline based on branch names or pipeline types.
>
> [...]
>
> `web` For pipelines created by selecting **Run pipeline** in the GitLab UI, from the project’s **Build > Pipelines** section.

Example:

A pipeline definition with a build and two deploy jobs. The build job is executed automatically, but the two deploy jobs are not added to the pipepline, because the pipeline is not started manually.

[image: non-manual pipeline]

### Combination

You could combine both, so only manually started pipelines add the job and the job is only executed if an user starts the job manually.

Example:

A pipeline definition with a build and two deploy jobs. The build job is executed automatically. The two deploy jobs are added to the pipelin, because the pipeline was started manually.

[image: manual job]